# jquerymobile pagecontainerbeforeshow only run when refresh page

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I´m develop my first hybrid app, and i work with jquerymobile 1.4.

the documentation suggests using method pagecontainer.
Well, i need populate dynamically one select whit certains values of a xml file, before show the page.
If debug app, this only runs when page recharge, not when open. (Chrome nav).
I tested in the device and does not work.
I read everything I found on the forum and have tried multiple ways but none of them work.

This is my code:

```
 $(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function(event, ui){
             if(ui.toPage.is('#buscar')){
                    $.get("auxfiles/regiones.xml", function (xml) {
                        $(xml).find("españa").each(function (idx ,v) {                        
                        $(v).find("item").each(function( i , vi) {
                        if ($(vi).text() === "Todas"){
                        $("#select-region").append('<option value = "' + idx + '" selected> ' + $(vi).text()  + '</option>');
                        $('#select-region').selectmenu('refresh');
                    }else{   
                        $("#select-region").append('<option value="' + idx + '"> ' + $(vi).text()  + '</option>');
                    }   
                    });                                                           
                  });
                });
            };

        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: i find another problem!
For view, please go to:
[Pagina de prueba](http://areaspain.com/test/index.html)
When page loads, its ok, but, if you click in "blue motorhome", open page "buscar.html" and footer image is very big, and select is not populating.
If click "refresh", all is ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jQuery Mobile loads buscar.html, it is actually just getting the contents of the first data-role="page" div and inserting that into the current page. This is the default AJAX navigation:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

So the script in buscar.html is not run and the image in the navbar is big because your index.css is still changing img tags within grids.

If you want to keep the AJAX navigation so you get nice page transitions, then move the script within the data-role="page" DIV, or even into the index page; and make you CSS for img size more specific.

The other option is to prevent AJAX navigation by adding data-ajax="false" to your links.

Comment: Thanks! it work. But only if i put the script into index.html, not in the div of second page. I think then the whole css should be in the file index.css and all the jQuery code in the head of index.html.